# Transform Laravel collection and group by key

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I would like to transform a collection of object in laravel, but I can't figure it out how. I want to group the record by the `type` column, and set the grouped record under an array key `value`.

```
public function transformData()
{
    $data = collect();

    $matches = [ 'race', 'ethnicity'];

    $attributes = Attribute::withTrashed()
        ->whereIn('type', $matches)
        ->get()
        ->groupBy('type');

    $data->put(
        $type, // to be the group key(like race)
        [
            'values' => $attributes->toArray(), // to be all the value with type race
        ]
    );

    dd(collect($data));
}
```

Here is what I'm getting:

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection^ {#2368
    #items: array:1 [
        "values" => array:2 [
            "ethnicity" => array:2 [
                0 => array:2 [
                    "id" => 1
                    "type" => "ethnicity"
                ]
                1 => array:2 [
                    "id" => 2
                    "type" => "ethnicity"
                ]
            ]
            "race" => array:2 [
                0 => array:2 [
                    "id" => 6
                    "type" => "race"
                ]
                1 => array:2 [
                    "id" => 7
                    "type" => "race"
                ]
            ]
        ]
      ]
      #escapeWhenCastingToString: false
    }
```

BUT I would like to return this instead:

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection^ {#2368
        #items: array:1 [
            "ethnicity" => array:2 [
                "value" => array:2 [
                    0 => array:2 [
                        "id" => 1
                        "type" => "ethnicity"
                    ]
                    1 => array:2 [
                        "id" => 2
                        "type" => "ethnicity"
                    ]
                ]
            ]

            "race" => array:2 [
                "value" =>
                    0 => array:2 [
                        "id" => 6
                        "type" => "race"
                    ]
                    1 => array:2 [
                        "id" => 7
                        "type" => "race"
                    ]
              ]
          ]
          #escapeWhenCastingToString: false
        }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO ... have you tried `$attributes->transform(fn ($item) => ['value' => $item])`?

Comment: @lagbox Thank you!!! But this will transform the key for each array to `value`